# How secure are sessions in PHP

Tags: php, session

So I'm fairly new to PHP and was wondering what is secure and what isn't with the user sessions.
So theoretically I have this site with user registration that saves user data in MySQL. When the user logs in the site it takes the id that corresponds with the username and password given in and save it to the $_SESSION variable. The site later on uses the $_SESSION value to get data from the database.

I would assume this would,'t be considered a secure website just from this basic stuff, but can the user change the $_SESSION value to be another users id with ease, or something like that, or if it's not that easy, what do I have to pay attention to, to make it more secure?

Explanations of why this is secure or why it's not secure/some info in PHP session security would be of great help.

Comment: If you don't create a script that let users freely modify session variables (by not checking user input), then you have nothing to worry about. Only thing that the client sends to the server is the session_id, usually in a cookie named `PHPSESSID`, which you can change/alter in the configuration. Session hijacking can be prevented by securing your site with HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

A session is stored on the server and cannot be accessed by the user. It is used to store information across the site such as login sessions.

The user cannot edit these values however the session's ID is stored on a computer through a cookie as a long random string. If an unauthorized user gains access to these strings it is possible for them to access the site